# Why wss 3.0 dosen't display image properly?

Tags: asp.net, html, .net-3.5, wss-3.0

I have my own custom webpart. Inside this webpart I would like to display transparent gif. Unfortunately it dosen't do it. I was tryign to use html img tag or asp.net image tag.
Src property for the image is set properly because it displays image icon insted of "X".
X would be proof of the wrong path under src. As I said it is alright. Can anybody help me and tell why I can't display my image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what to do to display the image.
Firstly:
Put the image to this path:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES
Second thing is to put url within server to this url insted of using disc path.
But does anybody know why does it work like this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it might not be a problem with WSS directly - have you tried using an HTTP proxy tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to ensure that the bits of your image are coming across the wire?